# Google cache links in search results

Tags: browser, cache, google-search

When searching for something while the target is offline its most convenient to click on Google's cache link for that certain target or search result. But I don't see such link on my android phone using the default browser. Is it related to mobile Google search? I wonder if I could reenable this. I use Android 2.3.3 with Samsung Galaxy S i9000.

Comment: Space is at a premium on a mobile screen. I expect that Google's mobile-optimized search results have dropped the link to the cache from the results. I know that search results have had a bit of a makeover recently any way and the cache link it hidden behind a mouseover event, which, of course, you can't do on a phone anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the bottom of the search results page, you will see something like (`View Google in: Mobile | Classic`), you can click on "Classic" to view the current search result in desktop version of Google, which of course have the 'cached' link.

Comment: Yes!, I've searched for this, but overlooked, Thanks!